# Quest'anno non farò/darò/porgerò gli auguri a nessuno

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

- Quest'anno non *farò* gli auguri a nessuno.
- Quest'anno non *darò* gli auguri a nessuno.
- Quest'anno non *porgerò* gli auguri a nessuno.

Quale è più corretto?

Comment: Fra tutte direi che personalmente suona meglio la terza.

Comment: Gli auguri non si danno; o si porgono o, più semplicemente, si fanno.

Answer (score 5):

*Augurio* viene dal latino *augurium*, la cerimonia con cui gli àuguri ricavavano presagi, tipicamente dal volo degli uccelli o anche dall'esame dei visceri di animali. Offrire *buoni auguri* significa quindi offrire o sperare buoni presagi e quindi, in senso traslato, un destino felice.

Perciò gli auguri non si possono *dare*. Diverso è il caso di una benedizione che infatti si dà o si impartisce.

Fra il burocratico *porgere* e il semplice *fare* preferisco certamente il secondo.